# how to automatically manage the serial in a database?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I have created an application in python which accepts values from the user and inserts them into the database . It accepts the name, address, phone numbers, etc from the application itself. But the problem is, the user can't enter the serial number into the application. Is there a way to manage the serial number automatically? Because no one remembers the serial number of the last record. So, one needs to check the serial number of the last record in the database every time before assigning the serial number for the new record.

I also want that if any record is deleted from the middle of the database, the serial number should be adjusted automatically. So, what I want is, the serial numbers should be assigned automatically like 1 for the first record, 2 for the next, 3,4,5,6... and so on. But if the record corresponding to the serial number 5 is deleted, then the s.no. 6 should become s.no. 5.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your first requirement is a standard auto-increment column. The second requirement is non-standard and has very questionable usefulness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out “auto increment” for your database, that way you can just insert data and serial number(it usually called id) will be assigned automatically.

As for the second part, this is really bad if you reference this table in another. Also this is a lot of extra computation for nothing, unless your application really needs this behavior.

If you really need to change ids on deletion check out stored procedures / triggers for your DB.